# asp.net - File Upload Control - Buffer Overflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, iis-6

I'm using a File Upload Control in my asp.net application. When I try to upload a file in my local environment everything works fine. When I try to upload a file on my testing server with IIS 7 everything works fine (after applying the correct permissions on the folder).

The problem is if I try to deploy my application to the production server that still uses IIS 6.0 I get an exception that he can't find the file. He doesn't throw any exception during the process. It just executes this code

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(filePath);
```

and then later when I try to access the file it is not there. I gave the folder every possible permission (ASPNET, NETWORKSERVICE, EVERYONE) that I could find on the internet and nothing helped.

I tried to dig deeper with the process monitor.The only logs from the process monitor that I could find were "buffer overflow" before it logged "name not found" from the filename.

Has someone an idea what I can do to get it working? Or to get a better error message? Why isn't he throwing an "access denied" exception or something like this if he can't upload the file?